# Running a batch (.bat) file from a VB macro (.vbs)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, call

I am having issues getting a simple batch file (opening command prompt) to run from a vbs macro, I know this question gets asked a lot and I have tried many different suggested solutions for this without success. I am using notepad ++ to run the scripts/VB code for testing.

I have verified that the .bat file will execute correctly by itself, any suggestion on how to get this to work correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for each instance.

VB CODE:

```
Sub CallBATCH()
    Dim argh As Double
    argh = Shell.Run "C:\Temp\cmdPrompt.bat"
End Sub
```

BATCH FILE:

```
start cmd.exe /k
```

---

EDIT: The following is the .bat file that I actually intend on calling up:

```
@echo OFF
title AutoCAD DWG Duplicator 
color 0a
:start
set /P TemplateName=Please enter the template name you wish to copy:
set /P NumberOfCopies=Please enter how many copies you wish to make:
set Pathname="<filepath>"
cd /d %Pathname%
:init
for /L %%f in (1,1,%NumberOfCopies%) do copy %TemplateName%.dwg C:\Temp\%%f%TemplateName%.dwg
```

Comment: Note: VBS and VBA are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling a `.BAT` file that in turn opens a command prompt with `START`. I'm unclear on why  you need the .`BAT` at all.

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /K"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

The */K* parameter will open the command prompt window and keep it open. You've supplied no parameters for `START` and no commands to execute when the command prompt opens so this should do what you are looking for. More at: [Run Method (Windows Script Host)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: sorry for the confussion, I was using the command prompt as an easy .bat file to call up, and then I could apply it to any instance where I needed to call up a .bat file. I went ahead and edited the question to show the .bat file that I want to call up.